# Redux architecture for a non-ui application

Tags: javascript, html, audio, redux, redux-thunk

I am working on an html5 audio player and I am trying to figure out if Redux would be a good solution even without a UI for the state (data) to flow in.

I will have multiple modules:

1. Playback Module: Encapsulate all callbacks from the Audio Element and dispatch an action after each callback to update the state.
2. Streaming Module: All the logic to figure out which segment is need at a given time, which segment to prefetch, ...
3. MediaSource Module: The media source module is wrapper of all actions of the media source and the source buffer.

Question 1:
the Audio Element has it's own state, playing, paused, seeking, currentTime, ... and the Redux state reflects the state of the Audio Element. 
Is that a good practice? I feel a bit concerned about having 2 states in different places and out of sync state...

Question 2: 
Who is updated first?
Let's imagine I want to Pause my player:

```
   //Implementation 1:
   function pause() {
     dispatch({type:'PLAYBACK_PAUSED'}).then(()=> {
       this.audio.paused = true; 
     });
   }

   // Implementation 2:
   function pause() {
     dispatch({type:'PLAYBACK_PAUSED'});
     this.audio.paused = true;
   }

   // Implementation 3:
   function pause() {
     dispatch({type:'PLAYBACK_PAUSED'});
     onPause();
   }

   function onPause() {
     const state = getState();
     if  (this.audio.paused != state.paused) {
       this.audio.paused = state.paused;
     }
   }
```

Question 3:
Every 0.5 second, the Audio element triggers a callback with a new current time. When this callback is trigger, I dispatch an action to update the current time in the state.
Now, the Streaming Module needs to be aware of that change in order to figure out which segment is needed at this given time and needed to know if we need to prefetch future segments.

How is my Streaming Module supposed to be aware of that state change?

Like that?:

```
currentTime = 0;
...
const state = getState();
if (state.currentTime !== currentTime){
 // Do Something...
 // Do Something Else...
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me try to tackle your questions one by one:

**Question 1**

Assuming that you are using the HTML5 audio component: there is nothing wrong about a redux state augmenting/syncing with a state of another component such as your audio player. In all cases, though, I suggest that the redux state **follows** the audio components state (should there be a delay for example)

If, however, you built the audio component yourself, maybe you can wire it into the redux ecosystem by dispatching events from it directly.

**Question 2**

Like I said in the previous answer, I would always go with pausing the actual component first, THEN update the state once the component acknowledges the pause. Code wise, this would mean triggering a dispatch when the audio component has fully paused (on an onPause callback for example). The reason for following the audio element in terms of state rather than expecting it to follow our state is because the element might not pause synchronously/immediately which could bring our states out of sync.

**Question 3**

When you dispatch the event to update the redux state every 0.5s, you could dispatch another event to your streaming module. For this, I suggest using an asynchronous action creator like so:

```
import StreamingModule from 'your-streaming-module';

export function updateTime (timeInMs) {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch({
            type: YOUR_UPDATE_ACTION
            time: timeInMs
        });

        // pseudo
        StreamingModule.fetchSegment(timeInMs);
    };
}
```

An alternative would be to subscribe to the store state directly. This all depends on how your streaming module is structured/instantiated:

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import StreamingModule from 'your-streaming-module';

const store = createStore(...);

store.subscribe(() => {
    StreamingModule.fetchSegment(store.getState().time.ms);
});
```

The latter might not work well unless you save the current time somewhere before you fetch the segment.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Now that I think about Question #2, onPause should only dispatch an action and somewhere else, react (with rxjs) to the state change and pause the audio element.
This way I have the ability to undo/redo actions